# How to obtain QueryList<ComponentA> in VIEW to pass to a service method

Tags: angular

How can I obtain a reference to a QueryList of ComponentA inside a view for ComponentParent to pass to a [service] method?  I intentionally mention it's a service method because I don't want to call a local method on my ComponentParent.  I want to call a method on a service passed into my ComponentParent's constructor.  There is no relationship between ComponentParent and ComponentA other than ComponentParent contains several ComponentAs, meaning no inheritance between ComponentParent and ComponentA.

Let's say I have a ComponentA and ComponentParent defined and I have several ComponentAs in my ComponentParent's view:

```
<ComponentA key="A"></ComponentA>
<ComponentA key="B"></ComponentA>
<ComponentA key="C"></ComponentA>
<ComponentA key="D"></ComponentA>
```

Then I have a button where I want the click event to call a service method that does something for each ComponentA component.  Something like this:

```
<button (click)="this.componentServices.ProcessComponents(QueryList<ComponentA>)">Click Me To Process All Components</button>
```

I don't want to use template reference variables for each of my ComponentAs because I want it to be automatic whenever a ComponentA gets added to ComponentParent.  So, I don't want to do this:

```
<ComponentA **#one** key="A"></ComponentA>
<ComponentA **#two** key="B"></ComponentA>
<ComponentA **#three** key="C"></ComponentA>
<ComponentA **#four** key="D"></ComponentA>
<button (click)="this.componentServices.ProcessComponents(**[one, two, three, four]**)">Click Me To Process Components</button>
```

I know I could call a local method on ComponentParent to do this (I'm doing this now) but would prefer to do it from the ComponentParent's view because I have lots of components like ComponentParent that contain lots of ComponentAs and would like to eliminate as much code in the ComponentParent type components as possible.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I would suggest 2 alternatives: 1. Write base class for ComponentParent for the duplicate code. 2. Have ComponentA add its self to a que on the service in it's ngOninit

Comment: 1. https://stackblitz.com/edit/querylistcomponenta-to-service-base-class
2. https://stackblitz.com/edit/querylistcomponenta-to-service-self-register

Comment: Can you inject the service in `ComponentA`? The service could emit an observable (e.g. by calling `Subject.next()`), and the `ComponentA` could subscribe to it. That way, you wouldn't need to maintain references to these components.

Comment: @WilliamLohan Thanks for going to the trouble of creating the stackblitzes for me!  I don't like approach 1 because there is no logical inheritance relationship and I don't want to create one just for this.  I somewhat like the idea of approach 2 (registering the ComponentAs with the service) but it still relies on the inheritance to trigger the processing.  I could actually get around that by instead calling the service component's ProcessComponents method directly from my view.  I am already calling other methods on that same service component from the view.  Continued...

Comment: @WilliamLohan However, I already had an @ViewChildren(ComponentA) components: QueryList<ComponentA> in the ComponentParent and realized I could reference it directly from the view so that's what I went with.  I really appreciate you taking the time to create the stackblitzes though and think I will gain some knowledge from your implementation, so thanks!!!

Comment: @ConnorsFan I like the idea of ComponentA subscribing to the observable and being responsible for what needs to happen but would be more complex to setup and since I realized I already had access to the QueryList<ComponentA> available in the view I went with that.  Thanks for giving me some ideas though!